# What is a field_base compared to a field_instance?

Tags: entities

What is a field_base compared to a field_instance? Is field base what is created with field_create_field()?

Comment: Those terms are [used in the Features module](https://drupal.org/node/1064472), in core terms a field_base is a field, and a field_instance is an instance of a field. The linked post does a good job of explaining the differences